# Cloud run converts request headers to lower case

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've created dotnet Api based application in cloud run and it got deployed successfully. I was expecting all the request headers will be received as it is when I'm invoking the application (even though http request headers are case insensitive).
But customer headers sent to application got received in the lowercase but headers like content-type received in the camelcase. I've also got information from the document

> By default, Cloud Run downgrades HTTP/2 requests to HTTP/1 when those requests are sent to the container.

Is this issue occurs due to that?

Please let me know is there any option in cloud run to receive request headers in the same case as it was sent to the application.

Comment: I recommend reading RFCs. HTTP header names are case-insensitive, RFC 2616 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt which was published in 1999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specification, the header keys are now (it has been updated Septembre 30 2019) case insensitive (and converted to lower case). The value of the header is case sensitive.

It's similar to HTTP/2 and QUIC (HTTP/3) specification and homogenous.

And there is no option to change that on Google Cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure is this application specific but I could find difference in sample dotnet and python applications which I've deployed in cloud run. In the sample dotnet application headers received in a lower case but in sample python application headers received in a camel case.